# Are WAR libraries visible and/or shared across web applications in same Java EE container?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, containers, web-deployment

I was reading about war deployment in "Head First Servlets and JSPs" when I came across this "The container put jar files inside WEB-INF/lib into its classpath"

My questions are :

1. As far as I understand, the classpath is shared across the jvm -I heard about classpath levels but I don't understand much and I didn't find a reference to it-, so does this mean that jar files included in one project is visible from other projects?
2. also does this mean that it is possible that we can have conflicts between 2 versions of the same jar deployed in 2 different applications if a third application is accessing this library while I forgot to include this jar in its lib folder?

I have been deploying web apps for years but I haven't come across any of these issues .... so I doubt I misunderstood something

Comment: I don't see a mention of classloaders in your question, likely that is the link you are missing to fully understand it. And by the way: the way you quote the book is not technically correct. That line should imply that the jars from WEB-INF/lib are put in the classpath of the web application, not the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gimby commented, the libraries are put on the webapp's classpath, which is handled by the webapp's `ClassLoader`. Each webapp having their own `ClassLoader`, they can't see or mix up each other's libraries.

Case two. The container does have its own classpath (and `ClassLoader(s)`), which means that if you have the same library loaded by the container *and* the webapp, you can get extremely confusing error messages telling you that "foo.bar.SomeClass cannot be cast into foo.bar.SomeClass".

Comment: can you provide me any documented reference to refer to and solidify my knowledge?

Comment: I suppose the Java EE specification would define that.

Comment: Generally each server/container has documentation that has a dedicated chapter to explaining classpath isolation; each server has a unique way of managing dependency scopes. Wildfly for example defines a module system to give you control over what is seen by the container and what is seen by deployed applications.